# On MacOSX, in C++, how to do interprocess communication over shared memory without spin lock?

Tags: c++, consumer, producer

I have two processes:

```
Producer
and
Consumer
```

they have a commonly mmaped shared region of memory

```
Memory
```

Now, Producer writes stuff to Memory. Consumer reads stuff from Memory.

```
I would prefer Consumer not to spin wait with Memory is empty.
I would prefer Producer not to spin wait when Memory is full.
```

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

how about using mutexes? since a mutex will sleep until the resource is available, you won't experience the spin-wait problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is reminiscent of the [Dining Philosophers Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dining_philosophers_problem).  If your platform supports it, you could use [condition variables](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/#ConditionVariables) *shared* across multiple processes.  With such shared conditional variables your `Producer` could signal your `Consumer` to read `Memory` when data is available, and vice versa when `Memory` is empty.  Remember to check for a [spurious wakeup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spurious_wakeup).

You'd need to check if MacOSX pthread implementation supports condition variables shared across processes.  See [my answer to your mutex related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2389353/do-pthread-mutexs-work-across-threads-if-in-shared-memory/2390654#2390654) to determine how.  The answer applies for condition variables as well.